# Correct timeline of a .ts file

Tags: timestamps, media

I have some MVs that is recorded from a TV, but timeline was incorrect somehow:

[image]

Anyone know some tool that can fix it ? The media plays fine, just the displayed stuff doesn't look good

Comment: @Kiwy of course not, it's just am incorrect label

Answer (score 1):

When I have problems with MPEG-TS files obtained by recording TV programmes, I usually try to demux them with [Project X](http://sourceforge.net/projects/project-x/), and then mux them again with `mplex` from command (from the `mjpegtools` package).

I recommend you to avoid Project X GUI because I find it poorly designed, and to run it via command line, for example:

```
java -jar ProjectX.jar -demux input.ts
```

Then you can run `mplex` with a command similar to the following one, depending on the files you get with Project X:

```
mplex -f 8 -o output.mpeg input.m2v input.mp2
```

This way you will get a fixed MPEG-PS file from your original MPEG-TS file.

It seems Project X works only with standard definition MPEG files, not with high definition ones.

Hope this solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you can live with mkv files instead, you can use tsMuxeR to demux the stream and then use mkvmerge from mkvtoolnix to create an mkv file bringing back all the demuxed files into a single mkv file. When creating the mkv file, some extra information is stored that might solve the problem for you.